# data can't view as time format. it's return as int

Tags: php, laravel

I stored my data at the database as Time Format, like '00:02:12'. then sum all the data:

```
foreach($pay_pending as $pending){
   $total_pay_pending += strtotime($pending->points_request);
}
```

and return it:

```
return response()->json(['status'=> 'Success', 'Cashout_pending' => $total_pay_pending], 200);
```

it returns me an int value. The output is

```
{
  "status": "Success",
  "Cashout_pending": 6073229120
}
```

but I need it time format. please, can anyone help me...?AS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your `add` logic to :

```
$total_pay_pending = 0;
foreach($pay_pending as $pending){
   $total_pay_pending += strtotime($pending->points_request)-strtotime("00:00:00");
}
```

And then `return` like -

```
{
  "status": "Success",
  "Cashout_pending": date("H:i:s",strtotime("00:00:00")+$total_pay_pending);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date` function to format it

```
return response()->json([
                 'status'=>'Success',
                 'Cashout_pending' => date('d M Y H:i:s',$total_pay_pending) 
                 ], 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code: (date formatting of timestamp)

```
'Cashout_pending' => $total_pay_pending
```

to

```
'Cashout_pending' => date('H:i:s', $total_pay_pending)
```